# ASP.NET MVC Actions chain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, pdf-generation

I have a controller which is used to generate a PDF. The content type of the response is application/pdf. But along with that I would like to return a json from the same controller. So I basically want one controller to perform 2 actions: return PDF and show a message to user. Is it possible to combine several actions with different content types in one Action result? Or is there some other way?

Comment: You can use `TempData` to show a message to your user, and have the FileResult as the return type of your action...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use multiple model in one Action Result and can view them. Please see the link for tutorial:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/